# Complex exponential with 2 pi

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I wonder why is it wrong to do the following:

$e^{i2\pi x}=(e^{i2\pi})^x=1^x=1$

for a real $x$ but not for an integer $x$

Comment: Is $\;j=i=\sqrt{-1}\;$ ? You can't apply just like that properties of **real** exponents in $\;\Bbb C\;$ . When you study the complex logarithm you will probably understand why.

Comment: integers are real numbers. What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

That is true if and only if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, else, I recommend you read on [roots of unity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity)